# Did Spock warn of disasters in the new Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, history, timeline, spock, star-trek-reboot

Did Spock Classic (in the new timeline universe) warn NuSpock of upcoming natural disasters? i.e. V'ger, the whale probe, Praxis and explosion, the Borg, violent first contacts, the wave from Generations, etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question in accordance with our future works policy.

Comment: It was future works when asked, perhaps. Now?

Comment: @Politank-Z - Probably not, given that Spock is deceased. Of course, most of the existing answers seem to be for another question....

Comment: [Welp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Beyond), not any more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whether he *will* is answerable only by waiting for the next movie.

Whether he *can* is another question (and the one I'll attempt to answer).

The events of the J.J. Abrams movie created a new timeline, so many of the events we've seen in the original timeline will no longer occur.  But we've also seen plenty of events that were set in motion by things that happened before the timelines split, and that would not be affected by the events of the movie, either the destruction of the USS Kelvin or the later events.

Here are some examples of threats that should still be approaching Federation space, and that Spock could warn about:

- [The Doomsday Machine](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Doomsday_machine).
- [The Space Amoeba](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Space_amoeba).
- [Nomad](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nomad)
- [V'Ger](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/V%27Ger)
- [The Borg](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg) (though the initial encounter, forced by Q, might be affected by the changed timeline)
- [The Whale Probe](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Whale_Probe)

The "butterfly effect" might prevent *some* of these, but it hardly seems realistic that it would prevent all of them. (Then again, realism isn't necessarily the deciding factor.)

The [Temporal Prime Directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Prime_Directive), as mentioned in Keen's answer, might theoretically prevent Spock from revealing this information.  On the other hand, I personally hope that he'd adopt the same attitude as Doc Brown in [Back to the Future](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/quotes):

> Marty McFly: What about all that talk about screwing up future events? The space-time continuum?
>
> Dr. Emmett Brown: Well, I figured, what the hell?

---

**UPDATE :** In the sequel movie, ["Star Trek Into Darkness"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1408101/?ref_=nv_sr_4), young Spock did consult with "Spock Prime" regarding the situation they found themselves in (avoiding spoilers):

> As you know, I have made a vow never to give you information that
> could potentially alter your destiny. Your path is yours to walk, and
> yours alone.
>
> That being said, ...

followed by advice based on his knowledge of the original timeline. He didn't literally say "Well, I figured, what the hell?", but it seems to be the same general idea.

Since Leonard Nimoy, sadly, is no longer with us, I presume old Spock won't appear in the next movie. I have no idea how they're going to handle that.

Comment: Thank you this my feelings as well. this is why i asked of large events not touched by the change in the timeline. the butterfly effect would do nothing for the ones mentioned above and need to be addressed in future movies/tv then again this timeline is only linked by Spock and the whole reason he is there Romulus sun going nova is a natural event- which means it will happen again! Oh and the temporal prime directive goes out the window since the whole event would be changed by temporal agents anyway back to 'normal'

Comment: +1 for being the only answer on this site I can remember that incorporated BTTF and Trek

Comment: Speaking of Q, why didn't he mess up the new timeline, knowing it might mess up his having fun with Picard?

Comment: @Zommuter: Q can probably hang out in whatever timeline he likes.

Comment: Ah yes, he could, he basically hinted at that in "All good things..."

Answer (score 9):

In the IDW comic #09 "[The Truth About Tribbles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Truth_About_Tribbles,_Part_2)" (considered a [canon source of information](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2012/07/straight-from-roberto-orci-current-trek-comics-are-canon) for the new Star Trek universe according to Robert Orci) this issue is specifically addressed by the crew of the Enterprise.

Old Spock encounters a tribble at the start of the two-parter but fails to inform the crew about the threat they pose. Later, nuSpock advises that he's discussed whether Spock-Classic is willing to give the Federation of info about *impending* threats. The answer is a definitive **"no".**

[image]

We can reasonably assume that this also applies to the threats you've mentioned above.

Comment: Sadly, there is also now a practical reason that Old Spock cannot be active in this timeline...

Comment: In " ...In darkness" he didn't seem so adamant.

Comment: Oh downvoter. Did you press the button for any special reason?

Comment: "No matter how grave the thread... Unless it's Khan."

Comment: @Kalamane - he does bear a bit of a personal grudge there if memory serves.

Comment: And let's not forget he violated this "rule" mere minutes later by giving Scotty the equations for transwarp beaming.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yup. He's surprisingly inconsistent for a Vulcan.

Comment: @Valorum: He was not human but, if he had been, I believe his response would have been, "go to hell".

Answer (score 7):

He can't do so.  The [Temporal Prime Directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Prime_Directive#Temporal_Prime_Directive) prevents him from interfering in events in the past, as he's technically a time traveler.

I guess he showed me, given his warning the Enterprise about Khan in *Star Trek: Into Darkness*. However, given Leonard Nimoy's death, it's exceedingly unlikely for him to appear again.

Comment: I feel this is more likely than that the events of the new timeline would prevent such disasters/plots.

Comment: Not even to prevent Berman and Braga from greenlighting Voyager?

Comment: Yes, and we all know how well Starfleet personnel have honored prime directives in the past :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I we'd talk about anyone but Spock I'd agree with you...but that cold-blooded vulcan... ;)

Comment: Spock could no more violate the Temporal Prime Directive than Kirk could violate the Prime Directive. Oh, wait ...

Answer (score 6):

No, because [it's a new timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21816/4056) (destruction of Vulcan, etc) so those events will not necessarily occur.  They *may*, but they will probably not.

Comment: V'ger is unrelated to Vulcan, nor is the Whale Probe (ST-IV) and so on...

Comment: According to the creator (J. J. Abrams), "The notion that when this one character arrived – Nero – that basically the timeline is altered at that moment. So everything forward is essentially an alternative timeline. That is not to say that everything that happened in the original series doesn’t exist. ... We are simply saying that from this moment in the opening scene of the movie, that everything people knew of Star Trek splits off into another timeline."  This is a new universe, events are different.  V'ger might hit a fragment of Vulcan and destruct before being a threat, etc etc etc.

Comment: @geoffc: Butterfly, meet hurricane :-)

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind the apparent time logic, the events that occured in the early movies will not occur again. First, like Spock said in the movie, because the destruction of Vulcan and the explosion of the USS Kelvin created a new course in time.

This change would prevent the director from repeating the story that was told before and give freedom to be creative.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the events leading to [V'ger](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V'ger), the [Whale probe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Whale_Probe) and the [Borg Threat](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg) start out way before Nero changed the timeline and will still happen. V'ger is still on it's way and so are the Whale Probe and the Borg (since there was a signal sent from the 22nd century to the Delta quadrant).

No matter what Nero did by coming back at the time he did ([2233](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nero)), it won't affect those events. Even if a new timeline was created, it's mostly a change to events immediately around Nero's arrival; it doesn't effect events happening before that.

Comment: Sure, but will Spock warn them?

Comment: Does this add anything that I didn't say in [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23306/3025) 4 years ago?

Comment: It's not even true. The producers have since stated that time changes rippled backwards, rather than merely taking effect from the moment Nero arrived in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Spock Prime logically might believe it is a moral obligation to prevent disasters that can be avoided, such as the future destruction of Romulus, the Klingon moon Praxis exploding, the whale probe, etc. Billions of lives could be at stake, and the needs of the many... The fact is that the timeline is so different now, what could it hurt to try and save that many lives? Entire planets are at stake. Isn't that what Kirk, Spock and the rest have always done? Why would it be any different now?

Comment: Present [canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83765/20774) suggests that he won't warn the crew, even where disasters are impending.